# Compaq tablet PC Stylus Cursor Position inverted on Fedora 12

Tags: fedora, tablet, calibration

I have a tablet PC, when I flip it to tablet position, I set the display settings to "Upside Down". Once I do this though, the cursor position when using the stylus is inverted. I'll have the stylus on the top right corner and the cursor will appear on the bottom left.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I know there are scripts out there that listen for a rotate event and the flip the stylus the right way, I can't find my bookmark though..

I know theres some in opensuse, a close brother to fedora, take a look around and you might find it